# Contribute Vs Contribute to

Tags: word-usage

According to [this dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contribute), when meaning "to be one of the reasons why something happens", "contribute" is an intransitive verb. But why is the quote using it transitively? Shouldn't it be "contributes to about 12%"?

> [Tropical deforestation contributes about 12% of the carbon dioxide
> emissions caused by human activity.](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2012/dec/19/what-is-redd-climate-change-deforestation) - The Guardian

Comment: Maybe the real problem here is that the Cambridge dictionary is very good for making definitions easy to understand, but leaves many usages uncovered. Try https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contribute. In general, when finding confusing results from one dictionary, check against another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "object" of the transitive use of ***to contribute*** is ***the thing or money contributed*** (***12% of*** total emissions, in this case).

If a preposition-based ***to-*** clause is included, it identifies ***the recipient of the contribution*** (***total*** emissions, in this case).

It might be easier to distinguish the syntactic roles of those two types of noun phrases connected to *the act of contributing,* by considering...

> 1: *He contributed **£1000** to the **charity fund***

...where...

> 2: *He contributed to the charity*  - FINE (don't know how much)
> 3: *He contributed £1000*   - FINE  (don't know who/what to)
> 4: *He contributed the charity fund to £1000*  - NONSENSE

---

The definition *to be one of the reasons why something happens* cited by the OP applies when the *direct* object (the thing contributed) is not specified, but the preposition-based *recipient* of the contribution ***is*** specified. As per their example usage...

> *Analysts agree that subprime loans contributed to the recession*

...where you might ask ***What** did those loans contribute?* To which the answer is *they contributed **to the cause*** (they made or encouraged the recession to happen).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does "contribute" mean in that quote? The bold definition doesn't make sense because it doesn't make sense to say deforestation gives emissions. **"to give something, especially money, in order to provide or achieve something together with other people"**

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it doesn't make sense to say deforestation gives emissions". They're not cutting down those forests to get wood - they do it to clear land for *farming*. So I'm sure nearly all the carbon-based plant material produced by forest clearance ends up being burned (i.e. - contributing *some* emissions ***to** total emissions*). Look again at the difference between *the thing contributed* (no preposition) and *what receives* the contribution (always preceded by ***to***) in my examples.